# How to get sum of rolling for each group based on different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
    date    hy_code curr_idx_diff   is_vol_price_up
24  2021/12/3   A   17  1
25  2021/12/6   A   2   0
26  2021/12/7   A   19  0
27  2021/12/8   A   20  0
28  2021/12/9   A   21  1
29  2021/12/10  A   22  0
30  2021/12/13  A   23  0
31  2021/12/14  A   24  0
32  2021/12/15  A   24  0
33  2021/12/16  A   20  1
34  2021/12/17  A   21  0
35  2021/12/20  A   22  0
36  2021/12/21  A   23  0
37  2021/12/22  A   24  0
38  2021/12/23  A   24  0
39  2021/12/24  A   19  0
40  2021/12/27  A   20  0
41  2021/12/28  A   21  0
42  2021/12/29  A   22  0
43  2021/12/30  A   23  1
24  2021/12/3   B   3   0
25  2021/12/6   B   4   0
26  2021/12/7   B   5   1
27  2021/12/8   B   6   0
28  2021/12/9   B   7   0
29  2021/12/10  B   8   0
30  2021/12/13  B   9   0
31  2021/12/14  B   10  0
32  2021/12/15  B   11  0
33  2021/12/16  B   12  0
34  2021/12/17  B   13  0
35  2021/12/20  B   14  0
36  2021/12/21  B   15  0
37  2021/12/22  B   16  0
38  2021/12/23  B   14  1
39  2021/12/24  B   12  0
40  2021/12/27  B   19  0
41  2021/12/28  B   20  0
42  2021/12/29  B   21  0
43  2021/12/30  B   20  0
```

**Goal**

- I want to assign column called `bkb` for each hy_code group, which computes rolling sum based on `curr_idx_diff` like below:

  ```
  df.assign(bkb=lambda x:x.groupby('hy_code')[['is_vol_price_up','curr_idx_diff']].agg(lambda x: x[0].rolling(x[1],1).sum()))
  ```

But got `KeyError: 0`

**Expected Output**

```
    date    hy_code curr_idx_diff   is_vol_price_up bkb
24  2021/12/3   A   17  1   NaN
25  2021/12/6   A   2   0   1
26  2021/12/7   A   19  0   NaN
27  2021/12/8   A   20  0   NaN
28  2021/12/9   A   21  1   NaN
29  2021/12/10  A   22  0   NaN
30  2021/12/13  A   23  0   NaN
31  2021/12/14  A   24  0   NaN
32  2021/12/15  A   24  0   NaN
33  2021/12/16  A   20  1   NaN
34  2021/12/17  A   21  0   NaN
35  2021/12/20  A   22  0   NaN
36  2021/12/21  A   23  0   NaN
37  2021/12/22  A   24  0   NaN
38  2021/12/23  A   24  0   NaN
39  2021/12/24  A   19  0   NaN
40  2021/12/27  A   20  0   NaN
41  2021/12/28  A   21  0   NaN
42  2021/12/29  A   22  0   NaN
43  2021/12/30  A   23  1   NaN
24  2021/12/3   B   3   0   NaN
25  2021/12/6   B   4   0   NaN
26  2021/12/7   B   5   1   NaN
27  2021/12/8   B   6   0   NaN
28  2021/12/9   B   7   0   NaN
29  2021/12/10  B   8   0   NaN
30  2021/12/13  B   9   0   NaN
31  2021/12/14  B   10  0   NaN
32  2021/12/15  B   11  0   NaN
33  2021/12/16  B   12  0   NaN
34  2021/12/17  B   13  0   NaN
35  2021/12/20  B   14  0   NaN
36  2021/12/21  B   15  0   NaN
37  2021/12/22  B   16  0   NaN
38  2021/12/23  B   14  1   2
39  2021/12/24  B   12  0   1
40  2021/12/27  B   19  0   NaN
41  2021/12/28  B   20  0   NaN
42  2021/12/29  B   21  0   NaN
43  2021/12/30  B   20  0   2
```

**For example**

- index=25, rolling 2(curr_idx_diff=2), sum=1.
- index=38, rolling 14(curr_idx_diff=14), sum=2.
- index=24, rolling 3(curr_idx_diff=3), sum=NaN because for B group, there's only 1 row.

Comment: could you include an expected outcome?

Comment: Can you explian more `x[0].rolling(x[1],1).sum())` ? Because `rolling` working by each column separately, so possible is necessary change completely your function

Comment: @enke@jezrael I update an example.

Comment: "based on curr_idx_diff" how is it based on that?

Comment: Hmmm, data `2021-12-07  000043  5.0     1`  - and description `because the sum of last 3 rows` ? Is based rolling by `curr_idx_diff` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes, rolling based on curr_idx_diff

Comment: so it means first row is 1 with rolling 17, second 0 with rolling 18 ? So all is NaN ?

Comment: @jezrael second is still 1.

Comment: Not understand. Mainly because in pandas rolling by 2 columns not exist by default. So is necessary some ugly hack I guess.

Comment: `rolling` is counted between scalar and Series, so it is confused `x[1]` in `x[0].rolling(x[1],1).sum())`. Or it means second value of column per group? Or it is per each row different?

Comment: @jerael per each row different and per group . That's why I used x.groupby('hy_code') first

Comment: So it could not work using define function to achieve it because pandas rolling function?

Comment: No idea what need. rolling working per column and scalar, e.g. rolling(3).sum() If scalar is dynamic what is ouput? How it working?

Comment: @jezrael sorry, I changed my example. My original data would compute np.nan.

Comment: I have idea - create new data sample - e.g. 5 rows in 2 group with explanation how it working. Expected ouput column is necessary.

Comment: @jezrael, I updated, is it clear?

Comment: why is `NaN` in `41  2021/12/28  B   20  0   NaN` ? And `42  2021/12/29  B   21  0   NaN` ?

Comment: @jezrael B group, index=41 there is 18 rows , so rolling sum would be np.nan